# how to make an application running on amazon ec2 accessible when port number 80 is closed to inbound traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

All,

I have a web application running on tomcat on an amazon ec2 instance and I have a DNS name on godaddy which redirects to this web app on ec2 with an elastic ip.

Everything works fine when I open the port number 80 to all inbound traffic but recently I received an email from Amazon support saying Denial of Service (DoS) attacks were launched from my instance to IP(s) xxx.xx.xx.xxx via UDP port(s) 80.

How can i make the application accessible by closing port 80 to outside world?

Thanks in advance, 
keran

Answer (score 0):

http is over TCP. Only open TCP on 80, keep UDP on 80 closed. The webapp should work.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a web application running on tomcat on an amazon ec2 instance and I have a DNS name on godaddy which redirects to this web app on ec2 with an elastic ip.

A re-directs is an HTTP thing (and not very effecient, nor good for bookmarking). Do you mean your web app has an A record?

> Everything works fine when I open the port number 80 to all inbound traffic

Yup, you need to open port 80 to serve traffic.

> but recently I received an email from Amazon support saying Denial of Service (DoS) attacks were launched from my instance to IP(s) xxx.xx.xx.xxx via UDP port(s) 80.

There are 2 possible explanations:

1) Your software is buggy and trying to send data to their box via UDP. This isn't that likely, but is possible if you accidentally enabled/misconfigured collectd, syslogd, statsd, or some other package.

2) Your software is buggy and let a hacker take over your box. It could have been your web application, or it could have been some other service (if you have other ports open to the world).

Either way, a good system administrator could use TCPDump to figure out where the problem is.

> How can i make the application accessible by closing port 80 to outside world?

You Can't. If you want to serve traffic to the world, you need an open port.  Blocking port 80 TCP will not fix your problem because "incoming traffic on TCP port 80" (used for web servers) has nothing to do with "outgoing UDP port 80". If your box is sending UDP traffic, then it's a broken/misconfigured program running on your box.

That said, you can use a proxy service like CloudFlare to "hide" your servers behind their load balancers. But that won't fix your fundamental problem, which seems to be that your box insecure.  If you are going to put a server on the Internet, you need to level up your security knowledge, or hire a system administrator.

If your content is "static" (i.e. not constantly changing, like a simple blog that's updated a few times per day), you should look into serving it from S3. S3 doesn't require a System Administrator, while EC2 does.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time and providing a detailed explanation!! You said http re-directs are not efficient-what do you mean by that?I have a A record in Godaddy which points to my Elastic IP of my EC2 instance.My application is running on tomcat and I have configured tomcat to run on port 80 so it would redirect to my application.Is there a better way of doing this?For the problem I have found out that I have enabled port 80 for outbound traffic by mistake.Like @BretzL suggested I have closed all ports except UDP on 80 closed.

Comment: A DNS record pointing at your server is the correct way to do it. A "redirect" is something different: It's not handled by DNS, but by having an additional web server and an additional web request.